# Generating Control Signals via Case statement vs Boolean function

Tags: verilog, computer-architecture, system-verilog, risc-v

I'm building a RISC-V processor recently, and I've encountered a question when constructing the control unit. That is, what's the difference between generating control signals through:

1. Case statement, selecting by using OPcode:

```
// Inst[6:0]
case (OPcode)
            // R-type
            7'b0110011: begin
                PCSel  = 1'b0;
                RegWEn = 1'b1;
                BrUn   = 1'b0;
                ASel   = 1'b0;
                BSel   = 1'b0;
                ALUOP  = 3'b010;
                MemRW  = 1'bx;
                LdSel  = 3'bxxx;
                WBSel  = 2'b01;
            end
            ...
```

2. And assigning control signals through its Boolean function from the truth table:

```
Branch = Inst[6] & Inst[5] & (!Inst[4]) & (!Inst[3]) & (!Inst[2]);
BrUn   = Inst[13] & Branch;
```

Does this difference have anything to do with the comparison between hardwired control unit vs microprogrammable control unit?
Any explanation and help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Tools these days can optimize almost anything, so your question has got to do something only with readability.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is readability and maintainability. The case statement is much easier to read and you can separate the functionality needed for each opcode. It's also much clearer which signals are don't cares (i.e. `LdSel  = 3'bxxx;`

The benefit of writing RTL is that it gives you a higher level of abstraction than writing everything out as boolean equations.